# PHP curl send public key

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to connect to an API and have been told that I need to send our public key to match the public key I sent them via email.

I'm setting the public key by using:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, [path to file]);
```

I'm getting this error:

> unable to set private key file: [path to file] type PEM

Am I missing something? I know that typically key-based encryption requires a private and public key but they specifically wanted me to send them the public key via email and specifically want me sending them the public key via code.

Comment: Have you tried CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE instead of CURLOPT_SSLCERT? 

   curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSH_PUBLIC_KEYFILE, [path to file]);

Default path is ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I also needed CURLOPT_SSLKEY which is the private key. Apparently cURL requires both, but sends only the public key?